# Is it worth keeping Aerondight on New Game+?

Tags: the-witcher-3

The description seems to imply it adjusts damage to the current level; is there better gear (or rather same gear but with higher stats) to be found on NG+?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 'Legendary' versions of all the Witcher gear and upgrades in New Game + with appropriately higher stats. Other gear you find will also have been scaled.

I haven't seen any comparisons of how Aerondight compares to these however my Aerondight is still good at level 84 (but I did get it while already playing New Game +).

If you have the Hearts of Stone DLC you can also get the Runewright to add sockets to the sword to make it even better.

Comment: Is the questline for finding recipes obvious to find or easter egged away somewhere?

Comment: What do mean by 'recipes'? The Legendary witcher gear just repeats the normal game Treasure Hunts.

Comment: I meant Diagrams. Found one already. Thanks for the response!